# update case query for multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I am using an UPDATE query to update multiple rows which is something like the following

```
UPDATE TBLNAME SET NEWCOLUMN =
CASE
WHEN TYPE='ACCOUNT' THEN 'FINANCE'
WHEN CODE='DATA' AND CLASS='FIRST' THEN 'LEGAL'
END
```

The above query works fine for single conditions and for certain conditions something like
`NEWCOLUMN = Audit when Type = file, fax, documents`, I was using something like

```
UPDATE TBLNAME SET NEWCOLUMN =
CASE 
WHEN TYPE='ACCOUNT' THEN 'FINANCE'
WHEN CODE='DATA' AND CLASS='FIRST' THEN 'LEGAL'
WHEN TYPE='FILE' AND 'FAX' AND 'DOCUMENTS' THEN 'AUDIT'
END
```

The above query works fine for the first two conditions but the third condition `AUDIT` is not updated.

Could somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
WHEN TYPE IN ('FILE','FAX','DOCUMENTS') THEN 'AUDIT' END
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but have one more issue: in the database when one row has their TYPE as FILE the above query works but in my situation I have multiple rows in my database where Type = FILE and running the above query updates only one row and the other rows with type "File" is not updated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It would be best to illustrate it by creating a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d8068/3/0                                               I was able to create the sample database but couldnt create the update  query there.                                                           I used the following update query                                             UPDATE dummy SET class =
CASE
WHEN TYPE = 'bank' THEN 'BANK'
WHEN CODE = 'LIA.OLA.NCL' THEN 'GST'
WHEN CODE IN ('RIA.IOA.JIK','OAK.OLK.PLA') THEN 'AUDIT'
END

Comment: The above piece of code, WHEN CODE IN ('RIA.IOA.JIK','OAK.OLK.PLA') THEN 'AUDIT' works only for the single row but not for multiples. ie it works for the Management row but not for the Advertisement row hope it clarifies, thanks